# Merging netCDF files (failed attempts of previous suggestions included)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, merge, netcdf, python-xarray

thank you for taking interest in my post as I know this question have been asked a couple of times on SO.
I am not very experienced in coding as I am relatively new, therefore I'm genuinely sorry if I'm asking some obvious questions.

I have tried most of the suggestions, except for cdo as it seems that it requires installation of certain software.

Although I have 135 files to merge but I believe there have got to be a way to merge them using codes rather than another software.

Below are the attempts and the errors I got:

Attempt 1

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset

year1 = netCDF4.MFDataset(['HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_15366.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_14990.nc',
'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11685.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11696.nc',
'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11724.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11748.nc',
'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11760.nc'])
```

#error: master dataset HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_15366.nc does not have a aggregation dimension

Attempt 2

```
test = xr.open_mfdataset(['HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_15366.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_14990.nc',
'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11685.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11696.nc',
'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11724.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11748.nc',
'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11760.nc'])
```

#error: Resulting object does not have monotonic global indexes along dimension timestamps

Attempt 4

```
ds = xarray.merge([xarray.open_dataset(f) for f in glob.glob('path/to/file/.*nc')])
```

#error: name 'xarray' is not defined

Attempt 5

```
ds = xr.merge([xarray.open_dataset(f) for f in glob.glob('path/to/file/.*nc')])
```

#error: name 'glob' is not defined

Attempt 4 and 5 could have been a code error such as changing

```
ds = xr.merge([xarray.open_dataset(f) for f in glob.glob('path/to/file/.*nc')])
```

to

```
ds = xr.merge([xarray.open_dataset(f) for f in glob.glob('1975 - 2016/.*nc')])
```

where 1975 - 2016 is the file name, but it did not work that's why I suspect it could be due to my poor coding

Attempt 6

```
import nctoolkit as nc
# read in the files

DATA2.drop(DATA1.variables)
# merge the files
DATA1.append(DATA2)
DATA1.merge()
# save the files as a netcdf file
DATA1.to_nc("merged.nc")
```

#error:  No module named 'nctoolkit'

I wholeheartedly appreciate your help! If you require any further information about the codes or files please let me know!
Thank you!

EDITED

Thank you spencerkclark for your help!
This is how it looks
[image: output of xr.open_dataset('HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_15366.nc)]

Comment: With attempt (2) what happens if you sort the list of filenames before passing it to `open_mfdataset`?  E.g. `test = xr.open_mfdataset(sorted(["file_b.nc", "file_a.nc"]))`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

I tried it and got the following error:

"Resulting object does not have monotonic global indexes along dimension timestamps"

Comment: Thanks for giving that a try -- it may be that we need to combine things manually.  Could you show the output of opening one of the files, e.g. `xr.open_dataset('HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_15366.nc')`?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question -- maybe one more thing to try before combining things manually -- could you try adding `combine="nested"` and `concat_dim=["timestamps"]` arguments to your `open_mfdataset` call?  E.g. `xr.open_mfdataset(files, combine="nested", concat_dim=["timestamps"])`.

Comment: #error: No module named 'nctoolkit' means you have not installed the package

Comment: @spencerkclark thank you so so much for your help, i used the code

```
 glacier = xr.open_mfdataset('HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_15366.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_14990.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11696.nc',
'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11724.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11748.nc',
'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11760.nc',combine="nested", concat_dim=["timestamps"])
```

and got another error: open_mfdataset() got multiple values for argument 'concat_dim'

But that also means we're getting somewhere.
I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @grace11 indeed we might be close.  I think you may just have a typo.  There should be brackets around the list of files, e.g.  `glacier = xr.open_mfdataset(['HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_15366.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_14990.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11696.nc', 'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11724.nc','HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11748.nc', 'HMA_Glacier_dH_1975-2000_RGI50_14_11760.nc'],combine="nested", concat_dim=["timestamps"])`.

Comment: it was able to run!!! Thank you so much @spencerclark! That was amazing, I really appreciate your patience and help for the last few days!